# How to optimize SOA requests in HPC

Tags: c#, soa, hpc

I want to use HPC to do some simulations, I'm going to use SOA. I have following code from some sample materials, I modified it (I added this first for). Currently I stumbled upon problem of optimization / poor performance. This basic sample do nothing expect querying service method, this method return value it gets in parameter. However my example is slow. I have 60 computers with 4 core processors and 1Gb network. First phase of sending messages takes something about 2 seconds and then I have to wait another 7 seconds for return values. All values come leas or more at the same time. Another problem I have is that I cannot re-use session object, that is why this first for is outside using I want to put it inside using, but then I get time out, or information that BrokerClient is ended.

Can I reuse BrokerClient or DurableSession object.

How can I speed up this whole process of message passing ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  const string headnode = "Head-Node.hpcCluster.edu.edu";
  const string serviceName = "EchoService";
  const int numRequests = 1000;
  SessionStartInfo info = new SessionStartInfo(headnode, serviceName);
  for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
  {
    using (DurableSession session = DurableSession.CreateSession(info))
    {
      Console.WriteLine("done session id = {0}", session.Id);
      NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);
      using (BrokerClient<IService1> client = new BrokerClient<IService1>(session, binding))
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < numRequests; i++)
        {
          EchoRequest request = new EchoRequest("hello world!");
          client.SendRequest<EchoRequest>(request, i);
        }
        client.EndRequests();
        foreach (var response in client.GetResponses<EchoResponse>())
        {
          try
          {
            string reply = response.Result.EchoResult;
            Console.WriteLine("\tReceived response for request {0}: {1}", response.GetUserData<int>(), reply);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
          }
        }

      }
      session.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Second version with Session instead of DurableSession, which is working better, but  I have problem with Session reuse:

```
using (Session session = Session.CreateSession(info))
{

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    count = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("done session id = {0}", session.Id);
    NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Transport);

    using (BrokerClient<IService1> client = new BrokerClient<IService1>( session, binding))
    {
            //set getresponse handler
            client.SetResponseHandler<EchoResponse>((item) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tReceived response for request {0}: {1}",
                    item.GetUserData<int>(), item.Result.EchoResult);
                }
                catch (SessionException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SessionException while getting responses in callback: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception while getting responses in callback: {0}", ex.Message);
                }

                if (Interlocked.Increment(ref count) == numRequests)
                    done.Set();

            });

        // start to send requests
        Console.Write("Sending {0} requests...", numRequests);

        for (int j = 0; j < numRequests; j++)
        {
            EchoRequest request = new EchoRequest("hello world!");
            client.SendRequest<EchoRequest>(request, i);
        }
            client.EndRequests();

        Console.WriteLine("done");
        Console.WriteLine("Retrieving responses...");

        // Main thread block here waiting for the retrieval process
        // to complete.  As the thread that receives the "numRequests"-th 
        // responses does a Set() on the event, "done.WaitOne()" will pop
        done.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Done retrieving {0} responses", numRequests);
    }
}
// Close connections and delete messages stored in the system
session.Close();
}
```

I get exception during second run of EndRequest: The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

Comment: you seem to be saying that your modification of the sample code has caused the problem you are seeing?

Comment: how many broker nodes are you using?

Comment: @Mitch Broker nodes, only one it is head node. Maybe my modification introduce this problem I think that there is a way to do it in more efficient manner, but I cannot find it. When I put 1 into this first for loop initialization, sending tasks and retrieving also take some time.

Comment: Any time you use more than one BrokerClient on the same session, you must give each BrokerClient instance a unique ID or you'll get an error the second time you call EndRequests.

The client's ID is part of how it matches requests to replies.  This mapping of requests to BrokerClient instances apparently happens when you call EndRequests. If you've already called EndRequests on a client with a particular ID, then calling EndRequests a second time on a BrokerClient with the same ID will cause an error, even if each call to EndRequests was done on a different BrokerClient instance.

Comment: I should add that all BrokerClient instances get the same ID if you don't explicitly supply one in the constructor.

Answer (score 4):

1. Don't use `DurableSession` for computations where the indivdual requests are shorter than about 30 seconds.  A `DurableSession` will be backed by an MSMQ queue in the broker. Your requests and responses may be round-tripped to disk; this will cause performance problems if your amount of computation per request is small. You should use `Session` instead.
2. In general, for performance reasons, don't use `DurableSession` unless you absolutely need the durable behavior in the broker. In this case, since you are calling `GetResponses` immediately after `SendRequests`, `Session` will work fine for you.
3. You can reuse a `Session` or `DurableSession` object to create any number of `BrokerClient` objects, as long you haven't called `Session.Close`.
4. If it's important to process the responses in parallel on the client side, use `BrokerClient.SetResponseHandler` to set a callback function which will handle responses asynchronously (rather than use `client.GetResponses`, which handles them synchronously).  Look at the `HelloWorldR2` sample code for details.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I still have a problem. How can I reuse Session. I'm creating BrokerClient on Session object, then I'm sending request and and the end I have to use EndRequest which seems to close whole session object, because when in the next loop I create another BrokerClient on this Session object I get exception at the EndRequest method ?

Comment: Did you reorder the `for` and `using` statements?  At the end of the `using` the session will be closed.